# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch:

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create custom multiple user types registration and I keep running into this error:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
> The main issue is I have not yet created any 'login' view function
> Here are my project urls

```
`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
]`
```

and these are my app's urls

```
 from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('customer_register/',views.customer_register.as_view(),name='customer_register'),
    path('business_register/',views.business_register.as_view(),name='business_register'),
]
```

these are the relevant view functions

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import Customer_userRegisterForm,Business_userRegisterForm
from .models import User,Business,Customer

def register(request):
    return render(request,'users/register.html')


class customer_register(CreateView):

    model = User
    form_class = Customer_userRegisterForm
    template_name = 'users/customer_register.html'

class business_register(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = Business_userRegisterForm
    template_name = 'users/business_register.html'
```

just in case it is important this is the relevant template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static  %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}",type="text/css">
    {% if title%}
    <title> {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title> Yatta </title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
<header class="site-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Yatta</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle"
                    aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
                <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Navbar Right Side -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {% if messages%}
            {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}}">
                {{message}}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif%}
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock%}
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to look at solutions to similar questions but none works for me. please help me solve the problem.

Comment: You have not created it, but obviously you are trying to use it somewhere, possibly within a template using something like `{% url 'login' %}`.

Comment: no, it's still a dead link in the template

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? What I'm saying is that your error is caused by that template tag.

Comment: i have not added such a template tag

Comment: Can you post the whole error with full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The urlpatterns in your project urls should be thus:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

The `django.contrib.auth.urls` contains django's built-in login view.